# Add TAX pecentage (%) in PDF invoice summary

Tags: magento-1.9, invoice, tax, pdf, totals

Does anyone know how to add a Tax % to the PDF invoice summary?

I've managed to add this info in to Items table, but can't manage to do the same in Summary.

[image: Preview]

Can anybody help me.

Thanks,

Comment: If you need more about the pdf you can try FireGento_Pdf: https://github.com/firegento/firegento-pdf

Comment: @FabianBlechschmidt thanks a lot, did not know that this extension exists. Very usefull. Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

Go to

```
System > Configuration > Sales > Tax > Orders, Invoices, Credit Memos Display Settings
```

Set `Display Full Tax Summary` to **Yes** and save config.

[image: Magento Invoice Full Tax Summary]

This should add the tax percentage to Magento's PDF Invoice. You can see the difference below.

[image: Magento PDF Invoice Tax Settings]